# Is it worthwhile to explicitly write Integers as bits in Swift?

Tags: swift, bit

I recently learned how the binary numbering system works (How to write Integers in bits), and was wondering if it was a worthwhile thing to include in my software. Performance is big to me, and I know that writing Integers in bits is faster than not. But I'm just wondering how much faster. I'm not asking for some number on a scale, I just want to know if it would be a subtle difference, like maybe a 0.1 second quicker calculation, or if it would be more noticeable, such as 1 second quicker.

Just thinking about the readability and safety of the code with explicitly written Integers in bits sounds like a mess waiting to happen, but I just want to know if the tradeoff would be worth it to me.

I know this is a bit of a loose question that I have stated, so let me try and improve it here:

Will my performance have noticeable change if I store my Integers explicitly using bits? (I consider "noticeable change" to be over 0.5 seconds quicker)

Comment: Never used swift, but what do you mean by writing integer as bits? In the end, numbers are always stored as a collection of bits in memory

Comment: I know that they are eventually turned into bits, but you are able to explicitly write out Integer values as bits, rather than an Int value. for example, instead of writing an Integer 3,  I could write 00000011. My question was if it was noticeably faster to do the latter.

Comment: No, not in almost every instance.

Comment: @JackBaer The conversion from `3` to `0b000000011` happens at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have thought you came from the '70s (like me) when "performance" was equated with "paging", "core memory", "megahertz", and the like. But then you prefaced things with "I recently learned...". Here's what **should** matter to you:

- What iOS/macOS version are you targeting as your baseline?
- Is your app graphically intensive? And if so, have you "handed off" what you can to the GPU?
- Are you efficiently using both threading and asynchronous calls? Specifically, are you accessing the "cloud" and/or any database you might be using properly?

There's many more questions you should consider *before* how to "write integers to bits", but if you get my drift, you shouldn't be concerned about such a thing. (And sure, graphics using a GPU instead of a CPU "kinda sorta" does what you are asking.

Last question, maybe the most important one: Have you actually tried something - anything at all related to what concerns you and is relevant to the app you are working on - on an actual device? (Be it a iPhone 5 or a MacBook Air.) I'm betting you won't have any concerns about the performance between how an integer is stored at the bit level.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I see what you mean about all the questions that need to be answered before performance.

Answer (score 2):

No, the compiler will generate the exact same code whether you write a number in binary, decimal or hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are already "written in bits" behind the scenes in pretty much all computer languages. It's very rare that you'll need to do more than simply use the integer types the language provides.

In very advanced circumstances you might have to do some bitwise operations but I wouldn't worry about that until you've done a lot more programming.